# Importing Existing Sqlite Database in Flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

I have this Sqlite database file inside the device's 'Documents' folder named **backup.db**. Now I have written function that should be able to import that database, but I am getting some weird **asynchronous** errors, not sure what I am doing wrong here, might need to add something. Here's the code for importing the existing file:

```
    class DbHelper {
  Future initDb() async {
    final dbPath = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
    final path = join(dbPath, '/backup.db');
    final exist = await databaseExists(path);
    if (exist) {
      print('db imported');
      await openDatabase(path);
    } else {
      print('creating copy of database');
      //try {
        //await Directory(dirname(path)).create(recursive: true);
      //} catch (_) {}
      //ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join(dbPath, '/backup.db'));
      //List<int> bytes =
         // data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
     // await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
    }
    await openDatabase(path);
  }
}
```

As far as I got, it gets the 'documents' directory, merges the path with **backup.db** file that already exists in Documents, then it should just import it if it exists. Let me know if there is anything I am doing wrong. I am using the **ext_storage** library to locate the documents folder and **sqlite** of course to be able to import the database.

And in another screen I call this function like this:

```
DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper();

onTap: () => dbHelper.initDb(),
```

Here's the stacktrace:

```
    [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: /backup.db
E/flutter (22458): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load
package:flutter/…/services/asset_bundle.dart:225
E/flutter (22458): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22458): #1      DbHelper.initDb
package:CWCFlutter/db/import_database.dart:21
E/flutter (22458): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22458): #2      _FoodListState.build.<anonymous closure>
package:CWCFlutter/food_list.dart:919
E/flutter (22458): #3      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:183
E/flutter (22458): #4      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:598
E/flutter (22458): #5      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:287
E/flutter (22458): #6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:259
E/flutter (22458): #7      GestureArenaManager.sweep
package:flutter/…/gestures/arena.dart:157
E/flutter (22458): #8      GestureBinding.handleEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:362
E/flutter (22458): #9      GestureBinding.dispatchEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:338
E/flutter (22458): #10     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent
package:flutter/…/rendering/binding.dart:267
E/flutter (22458): #11     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:295
E/flutter (22458): #12     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:240
E/flutter (22458): #13     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:213
E/flutter (22458): #14     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)
E/flutter (22458): #15     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (22458): #16     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (22458): #17     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:265:10)
E/flutter (22458): #18     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:174:5)
```

**updated code**

```
  class DbHelper {
  Future<void> initDB() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String newPath = join(documentsDirectory.path, '/backup.db');
    final exist = await databaseExists(newPath);
    print("This print works.");
    if (!exist) {
      try {
        final dbPath = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
        final path = join(dbPath, '/backup.db');
        File(path).copySync(newPath);
        print("This print doesn't work.");
      } catch (_) {}
    }
  }

  Future<Database> openDB() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, '/backup.db');

    await initDB();
    Database db = await openDatabase(path);

    return db;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried `flutter clean` but still getting the same error, mostly ``asynchronous suspension``

Comment: Can you add an error to the question?

Comment: Post your errors StackTrace

Comment: added StackTrace in original post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join(dbPath, '/backup.db'));
```

You are trying to load `"/backup.db"` from the asset bundle adding `dbPath` to the key.

You need to add the `backup.db` to the `assets` folder if you want to load the database this way.

If you know the location of the `.db` file and it's not in the `assets` then why do you need to import it? Just open it.

You can copy the database to another location using `File(path).copy(String newPath)`

```
Future<void> initDB() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String newPath = join(documentsDirectory.path, '/backup.db');
    final exist = await databaseExists(newPath);
    if (!exists) {
        try {
            final dbPath = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
            final path = join(dbPath, '/backup.db');
            File(path).copySync(newPath);
        } catch (_) {}
     }
}

Future<Database> openDB() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, '/backup.db');
    await initDB();
    Database db = await openDatabase(path);
    return db;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out. I know the exact path of the file, it is always here: `final dbPath = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
    final path = join(dbPath, '/backup.db');`

Comment: Could you give me the code on how it would work out in my context? I've been trying out to do it this way, but I still get errors, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong @Sergey Inshev

Comment: @arbiter I've updated the answer with a code snippet. This code will look for the database within the ApplicationDocumentsDirectory. If not found will copy the database from the ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS

Comment: I appreciate your help, let me see how to link it all up and I'll get back to you asap. Just one more question, how would I initialize this function onTap? I suppose I would call openDB()? @Sergey Inshev

Comment: @arbiter call for async openDB() in your onTap. openDB() returns the Future<Database>. If you await for openDB(), you'll get a Database object, which you can use to make calls to your database.

Comment: I am still getting `asynchronous` errors when I click the button, not sure what the issue is, but I will figure it out.

Comment: @arbiter please provide a stacktrace

Comment: updated the main code, the thing is, when button is clicked, there is no error, so I tried to debug with print, and only one print fires, and the other one doesn't sort of like the function stops mid way. When clicked, nothing happens.

Comment: you should call the function with await -> "await openDB()"